# Popup, non-modal, in-line Dialog in PyQT

Tags: python, dialog, pyqt, pyqt4

It's difficult to describe what I want to do here, so here's what I want:

-Click a button that "pops up" a dialog.

-This dialog, however, should be non-modal.

-I'd also like for it to be sort of 'locked' with the parent app so if I moved it, it too would come with.

It seems like i'm more or less trying to describe an in-line popup, but I'm not sure if that's what it's called, or even how I should go about approaching this problem. So, PyQt gurus, how would you make something like this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be a dialog? You can have a widget on main window that will be shown/hidden with a button. Sort of like "show more" stuff in some GUI's.

Comment: I suppose that might take some fancification, but I suspect that might do what I want it to in the end.

Comment: @ekhumoro's answer addresses all but the "locked" aspect. I've never seen such a thing implemented, but I suppose you could, if you wanted, hook into the child's move event and move the parent with it... though that would be strange. Is there a common app that you've seen do that that you're trying to emulate?

Comment: Turned out just to be bad app methodology. I wound up getting what I wanted by using a "hidden" tabWidget that I could just switch between indices.

Answer (score 5):

To get a modeless dialog, open it with [show()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#show) rather than [exec_()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec).

To ensure that the dialog is "locked with the parent app", set a parent window in the dialog's constructor.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Open Dialog', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.handleOpenDialog)
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self._dialog = None

    def handleOpenDialog(self):
        if self._dialog is None:
            self._dialog = QtGui.QDialog(self)
            self._dialog.resize(200, 100)
        self._dialog.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

for Qt5:

I ignore why `dialog.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)` won't work, but

```
dialog.run()
dialog.exec_()
```

will do. `run` will make the dialog non modal and `exec_` will block it until the user input.