# How to create an independent non-modal dialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog, modeless

I'm trying to extend this solution [Non modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969319/popup-non-modal-in-line-dialog-in-pyqt/7970172#7970172)

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
dialog = None


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle('A floating dialog')
        self.resize(250,250)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open Dialog', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.handleOpenDialog)
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self._dialog = None
        global dialog
        dialog = Dialog(self)
        dialog.show()

    def handleOpenDialog(self):
        if self._dialog is None:
            self._dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog(self)
            self._dialog.resize(200, 100)
        self._dialog.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Apology if title wasn't relevant. I want to have a dialog/window that is independent of all existing window/dialogs, and can be always interacted with, i.e. GUI loop of application window/any dialogs doesn't block this non-model dialog. For simplicity, I have used global variable `dialog` in above code snippet which will hold the non-modal dialog instance.

When above program is run, the main window appears along-with the non-modal dialog, and both dialogs are user interactive, but when the button is clicked, the GUI loop of `self._dialog` starts, and user can no longer interact with the floating dialog, and application window. What I want is to be able to interact with `dialog` but not with `Window`

I want behavior similar to the example below:

[image]

I opened help dialog from main window, then I opened a non-modal dialog which appears on top of the main window, and can not interact with the main window, but still doesn't block help dialog/window and allows user to interact with this non-modal window i.e. the help dialog in the example.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you. You already created an instance of your `Dialog`, why are you creating a *new* instance of QDialog? What is the expected result when you click the button?

Comment: When I click the button in main window,  `handleOpenDialog` is called which starts GUI loop for `self._dialog` with `self._dialog.exec_()`, then `global dialog` can't be interacted with. I want to make `global dialog` interactable. I found somewhere that multi-processing can be used for this kind of behavior, but then sharing of the data between the dialogs will be difficult.

Comment: So, in `handleOpenDialog` you want to open a *new* dialog (which is modal), but you still want to be able to interact with your `Dialog` in the meantime? Why do you need to run the dialog's loop? As the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec), "`exec` Shows the dialog as a modal dialog", so if you don't want that, you should just call `show` and eventually connect to the `finished`, `accepted` or `rejected` signals.

Comment: Yeah that is True, but then `Window` will also be interactable if I open handleDialog also as non-modal calling `show`, which I don't want, because the dialog I'm trying to make floating is a help dialog, so it makes sense to make it always interactable. Let me add such an example in the question.

Comment: @musicamante, I have tried to add a demonstrative image with explanation.

Comment: Then what about creating the `Dialog` without *any* parent (note that this means that you could also use a basic QWidget), while setting the QDialog modality to `WindowModal` and then use `show()`? This will make your Dialog independent from both the main window *and* the modal dialog.

Comment: @musicamante, Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: @musicamante, I tried `self.setModal(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)` in `Dialog` class without passing the parent to `dialog` instance, but then it is blocking all the interaction to `MainWindow` and I can not click on `MainWindow` until I close this dialog. I even tried `setParent(None)` explicitly, but it still  doesn't work.

Comment: Please carefully read what I write: that modality flag is for the new **QDialog** you're creating, and that *requires* the parent; it's not for *your* Dialog class, which has not to be necessarily a QDialog subclass, and should **not** have a parent in any case.

Comment: @musicamante, I got it. Thank you for your support, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a dialog is opened with `exec()`, it will default to being [application-modal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum). This means it will block all other windows in the application, regardless of whether they're parented to other windows or not. To make a dialog modal for only *one* window, it must be parented to that window and also have its modality explicitly set to [window-modal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowModality-enum).

For a dialog to be fully non-modal with respect to all other windows (and any of their modal dialogs), it must have no parent and then be opened with `show()`. However, a side-effect of this is that it won't be automatically closed when the main-window is closed. To work around this, it can be explicitly closed in the `closeEvent()` of the main-window.

Here is a simple demo that implements all of the above:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setGeometry(400, 100, 300, 200)
        self._help_dialog = None
        self._other_dialog = None
        self.buttonHelp = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open Help')
        self.buttonHelp.clicked.connect(self.handleOpenHelp)
        self.buttonDialog = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open Dialog')
        self.buttonDialog.clicked.connect(self.handleOpenDialog)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonDialog)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonHelp)
        self.handleOpenHelp()

    def handleOpenDialog(self):
        if self._other_dialog is None:
            self._other_dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog(self)
            self._other_dialog.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
            self._other_dialog.setWindowTitle('Other Dialog')
            self._other_dialog.resize(200, 100)
        self._other_dialog.exec_()

    def handleOpenHelp(self):
        if self._help_dialog is None:
            self._help_dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
            self._help_dialog.setWindowTitle('Help Dialog')
            self._help_dialog.setGeometry(750, 100, 250, 250)
        self._help_dialog.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self._help_dialog is not None:
            self._help_dialog.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```